# Reading context parameter in Spring Java Config class

Tags: spring

I have defined a parameter in tomcat context file-

```
<Parameter name="filePath" value="C:/test/test.properties" override="false"/>
```

I want to to read this parameter in Configuration class of Spring using contextParameter bean but I am getting null value. Please suggest how to read this value in this class. When I am doing same in any other class I am getting the expected value.  My Code is below:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebAppConfig {

//Using value annotation and contextParameter bean for reading value
@Value("#{contextParameters.filePath}")
private String filePath;

// Want to use that context Parameter to load propertiy file
@Bean
public  PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {

    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurerBean = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();     
    propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurerBean.setLocations(new Resource[]{new FileSystemResource(filePath)});
    return propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurerBean;
}
```

Comment: Add escape character to file path C://test//test.properties ....

Comment: filePath is null. Its not getting initialized.

Comment: How do you know filepath is null? Have u printed it? In above code you are passing it directly to filesystemresource which will never get initialized due to wrong path.

Comment: I debugged in eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property should be available via the [Environment](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/Environment.html), which means you should be able to refer to it directly as:

```
@Value("${filePath}")
private String filePath;
```

or obtain it via an autowired enviroment bean, for example:

```
@Bean
public String filePath(Environment environment) { 
    return environment.getProperty("filePath");
}

@Value("#{filePath}")
private String filePath;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I had to change the code little. I injected Environment in PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer and used environment.getProperty("filePath") there  as this bean was getting created before. @Value("${filePath}") did not work for me.